# Dynamically create Bootstrap alerts box through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.0 for my project and I would like to dynamically add Bootstrap alert box in my page (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts). I want to do something like:

```
bootstrap-alert.warning("Invalid Credentials");
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try this (see a working example of this code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/7ATLS/1/)

```
<input type = "button" id = "clickme" value="Click me!"/>
<div id = "alert_placeholder"></div>
<script>
bootstrap_alert = function() {}
bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message) {
            $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>'+message+'</span></div>')
        }

$('#clickme').on('click', function() {
            bootstrap_alert.warning('Your text goes here');
});
</script>​
```

**EDIT**: There are now libraries that simplify and streamline this process, such as [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/)

Comment: To comply with the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) you should add .alert-dismissable to your div.

Comment: can`bootstrap_alert = function()  {}` be shortcut to `bootstrap_alert = {}` ?

Answer (score 44):

```
/**
  Bootstrap Alerts -
  Function Name - showalert()
  Inputs - message,alerttype
  Example - showalert("Invalid Login","alert-error")
  Types of alerts -- "alert-error","alert-success","alert-info","alert-warning"
  Required - You only need to add a alert_placeholder div in your html page wherever you want to display these alerts "<div id="alert_placeholder"></div>"
  Written On - 14-Jun-2013
**/

  function showalert(message,alerttype) {

    $('#alert_placeholder').append('<div id="alertdiv" class="alert ' +  alerttype + '"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>'+message+'</span></div>')

    setTimeout(function() { // this will automatically close the alert and remove this if the users doesnt close it in 5 secs


      $("#alertdiv").remove();

    }, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: Excellent!  In Bootstrap 3 the alerts are `.alert-success, .alert-info, .alert-warning & .alert-danger`

Comment: But when you make another before you remove this one, it'll make id conflict.

Answer (score 9):

You can also create a HTML alert template like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" id="alert_template" style="display: none;">
    <button type="button" class="close">×</button>
</div>
```

And so you can do in JavaScript this here:

```
$("#alert_template button").after('<span>Some text</span>');
$('#alert_template').fadeIn('slow');
```

Which is in my opinion cleaner and faster. In addition you stick to Twitter Bootstrap standards when calling `fadeIn()`.

To guarantee that this alert template works also with multiple calls (so it doesn't add the new message to the old one), add this here to your JavaScript:

```
$('#alert_template .close').click(function(e) {
    $("#alert_template span").remove();
});
```

So this call removes the span element every time you close the alert via the x-button.

Answer (score 7):

I created this VERY SIMPLE and basic plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        bs_alert: function(message, title){
            var cls='alert-danger';
            var html='<div class="alert '+cls+' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
            if(typeof title!=='undefined' &&  title!==''){
                html+='<h4>'+title+'</h4>';
            }
            html+='<span>'+message+'</span></div>';
            $(this).html(html);
        },
        bs_warning: function(message, title){
            var cls='alert-warning';
            var html='<div class="alert '+cls+' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
            if(typeof title!=='undefined' &&  title!==''){
                html+='<h4>'+title+'</h4>';
            }
            html+='<span>'+message+'</span></div>';
            $(this).html(html);
        },
        bs_info: function(message, title){
            var cls='alert-info';
            var html='<div class="alert '+cls+' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>';
            if(typeof title!=='undefined' &&  title!==''){
                html+='<h4>'+title+'</h4>';
            }
            html+='<span>'+message+'</span></div>';
            $(this).html(html);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Usage is

```
<div id="error_container"></div>
<script>
$('#error_container').bs_alert('YOUR ERROR MESSAGE HERE !!', 'title');
</script>
```

first plugin EVER and it can be easily made better

Comment: you can even add a `bs_close: function(){$('.alert').alert('close');}`

Answer (score 4):

Found this today, made a few tweaks and combined the features of the other answers while updating it to bootstrap 3.x.  NB: This answer requires jQuery.

In html:

```
<div id="form_errors" class="alert alert-danger fade in" style="display:none">
```

In JS:

```
<script>
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082330/dynamically-create-bootstrap-alerts-box-through-javascript
function bootstrap_alert(elem, message, timeout) {
  $(elem).show().html('<div class="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button><span>'+message+'</span></div>');

  if (timeout || timeout === 0) {
    setTimeout(function() { 
      $(elem).alert('close');
    }, timeout);    
  }
};
</script>​
```

Then you can invoke this either as:

```
bootstrap_alert('#form_errors', 'This message will fade out in 1 second', 1000)
bootstrap_alert('#form_errors', 'User must dismiss this message manually')
```

Answer (score 4):

just recap:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button').on( "click", function() {

      showAlert( "OK", "alert-success" );

    } );

});

function showAlert( message, alerttype ) {

    $('#alert_placeholder').append( $('#alert_placeholder').append(
      '<div id="alertdiv" class="alert alert-dismissible fade in ' +  alerttype + '">' +
          '<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" >×</a>' +
          '<span>' + message + '</span>' + 
      '</div>' )
    );

    // close it in 3 secs
    setTimeout( function() {
        $("#alertdiv").remove();
    }, 3000 );

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
<button onClick="" >Show Alert</button>
      
<div id="alert_placeholder" class="container" ></div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/antelove/pen/MWgvPVZ)

Answer (score 2):

FWIW I created a JavaScript class that can be used at run-time.
It's over on [GitHub, here](https://github.com/JustCarty/BootstrapAlerts).

There is a readme there with a more in-depth explanation, but I'll do a quick example below:

```
var ba = new BootstrapAlert();
ba.addP("Some content here");
$("body").append(ba.render());
```

The above would create a simple primary alert with a paragraph element inside containing the text "Some content here".

There are also options that can be set on initialisation.
For your requirement you'd do:

```
var ba = new BootstrapAlert({
    dismissible: true,
    background: 'warning'
});
ba.addP("Invalid Credentials");
$("body").append(ba.render());
```

The `render` method will return an HTML element, which can then be inserted into the DOM. In this case, we append it to the bottom of the body tag.

This is a work in progress library, but it still is in a very good working order.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using toastr (https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) with style modifications  [Make toastr alerts look like bootstrap alerts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066882/make-toastr-alerts-look-like-bootstrap-alerts)

Answer (score 1):

```
function bootstrap_alert() {
        create = function (message, color) {
            $('#alert_placeholder')
                .html('<div class="alert alert-' + color
                    + '" role="alert"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>' + message
                    + '</span></div>');
        };
        warning = function (message) {
            create(message, "warning");
        };
        info = function (message) {
            create(message, "info");
        };
        light = function (message) {
            create(message, "light");
        };
        transparent = function (message) {
            create(message, "transparent");
        };
        return {
            warning: warning,
            info: info,
            light: light,
            transparent: transparent
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that [AlertifyJS](http://alertifyjs.com/alert.html) is a better alternative and have a Bootstrap theme.

```
alertify.alert('Alert Title', 'Alert Message!', function(){ alertify.success('Ok'); });
```

Also have a **4 components**: **Alert**, **Confirm**, **Prompt** and **Notifier**.

Exmaple: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loginet/1y6zzfhn/)