# jQuery: alert removes the div tag when clicked close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My `ajax` looks like

```
   // send the data to the server using .ajax() or .post()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'addVideo',
        data: {
            video_title: title,
            playlist_name: playlist,
            url: id
            // csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
        },
        done: notify('success', 'video saved successfully'),
        fail: notify('error', 'There were some errors while saving the video. Please try in a while')
    });
```

`notify` looks like

```
function notify(notify_type, msg) {
    var alerts = $('#alerts');
    alerts.addClass('alert');
    alerts.append('<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>');
    if (notify_type == 'success') {
      alerts.addClass('alerts-success').append(msg).fadeIn('fast');
    }
    if (notify_type == 'failure') {
      alerts.addClass('alerts-error').append(msg).fadeIn('fast');
    }
}
```

- When I save click on button I get success message as

> video saved successfully                                                    x(cross mark)

- I click cross and notification is gone now
- When I AGAIN save click on button, nothing happens, I see firebug complaining 
  `No elements were found with the selector: "#alerts"`
- My guess is clicking on cross mark removes the `div="alerts"` tag entirely from DOM. is it correct?

**Question**
- How can I get the correct behavior. clicking on cross mark removes notification div, clicking on button to create creates the notification div again

Comment: Where is your code for when you click the close link in your alert?

Comment: I don nothing, I depend on `alerts.append('<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>');`

Comment: may be you stop telling twitter bootstarap in each question ? it looks like ad now. and make ppl to ignore the question even if it simple js problem

Comment: What happens when you click that `x`? There must be some code that runs to close the alert, otherwise clicking it would just scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: When I click `x` , div goes away

Comment: ok, but WHY? Is it something Twitter Bootstrap is doing? Dig into the code, find out why things happen the way they do. If the default behavior is to remove the alert when it closes then either close it using some other method or recreate it each time you need it.

Comment: Could I ask you to post a simple demo, to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, that reproduces your problem so we can see what's happening? And work out what's going wrong more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually according to [**this**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js) when you click `x` the plugin removes the div so when you try to select the `div` again using `var alerts = $('#alerts');` after you close it once the `div` is not present in the `dom`.

A part of the plugin that is responsible for close/remove an element

```
function removeElement() {
  $parent
    .trigger('closed')
    .remove()
}

$.support.transition && $parent.hasClass('fade') ?
  $parent.on($.support.transition.end, removeElement) :
  removeElement()
```

Try to create a dynamic div each time (with id `alerts`) and append it to the body where you want to place it, it may work.

Comment: thank you for help, I got the right direction and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082330/dynamically-create-bootstrap-alerts-box-through-javascript

Comment: Here's another approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494887/my-bootstrap-alert-will-not-display-after-being-closed/20495097#20495097

Answer (score 1):

As Sheikh Heera says, you can fix this in the plugin by changing

```
function removeElement() {
  $parent
  .trigger('closed')
  .remove()
}
```

to

```
function removeElement() {
  $parent
  .trigger('closed')
  .hide()
}
```

Comment: So you suggest hacking the "core"? Bad idea.