# Make toastr alerts look like bootstrap alerts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, toastr

I'd like to make toastr's popup look the same as, or very close to, Bootstrap alerts.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Include the CSS for the Bootstrap alerts, then in your toastr options, change the values of toastClass and iconClasses:

```
toastr.options = {
    toastClass: 'alert',
    iconClasses: {
        error: 'alert-error',
        info: 'alert-info',
        success: 'alert-success',
        warning: 'alert-warning'
    }
},
```

Then in toastr's CSS, remove the dropshadow from `#toast-container > div` so that it ends up looking like:

```
#toast-container > div {
    width: 300px;
}
```

You could leave the padding if you wanted, or add that to your own CSS file instead of editing toastr's (probably best, just make sure yours is loaded afterwards).

Comment: Lovely job - thank you very much!  Yes, I left the CSS as the colouring was enough to stop the two alerts clashing visually.

Answer (score 5):

To make them the same as bootstrap 3.2.0, i used a combination of the selected answer - although `alert-error` should be `alert-danger` - and this gist, which replaces the icons with fontawesome icons

https://gist.github.com/askehansen/9528424

To make them look exactly the same i also

- set the opacity of the toasts to 1
- changed the title and message colour to match bootstrap

css is

```
#toast-container > div {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

#toast-container > .alert {
    background-image: none !important;
}

#toast-container > .alert:before {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    margin: auto 0.5em auto -1.5em;
}

#toast-container > .alert-info:before {
    content: "\f05a";
}
#toast-container > .alert-info:before,
#toast-container > .alert-info {
    color: #31708f;
}

#toast-container > .alert-success:before {
    content: "\f00c";
}
#toast-container > .alert-success:before,
#toast-container > .alert-success {
    color: #3c763d;
}

#toast-container > .alert-warning:before {
    content: "\f06a";
}
#toast-container > .alert-warning:before,
#toast-container > .alert-warning {
    color: #8a6d3b;
}

#toast-container > .alert-danger:before {
    content: "\f071";
}
#toast-container > .alert-danger:before,
#toast-container > .alert-danger {
    color: #a94442;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This post is a little old, but I thought I would add another possible solution.

I found the default bootstrap "alert" color scheme was a little light for the toastr messages. I used a custom LESS file and did the following to darken them.

```
#toast-container {
   @darken-amount: 10%;

   .toast-error {
      background-color: darken(@brand-danger, @darken-amount);
   }

   .toast-warning {
      background-color: darken(@brand-warning, @darken-amount);
   }

   .toast-success {
      background-color: darken(@brand-success, @darken-amount);
   }

   .toast-info {
     background-color: darken(@brand-info, @darken-amount);
   }
}
```

Optionally, you can also change the color of the text in the message:

```
.toast-message {
   color: #000;
}
```