# Twitter Bootstrap alert (notification) dynamically change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Simple question, but I didn't succeed finding a satisfactory answer on SO.

When I have a bootstrap alert:

```
<div id='alert' class='alert alert-error hide'>Alert.</div>
```

I want the text to be controlled using either Javascript of by jQuery, I just looked at this solution to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082330/dynamically-create-bootstrap-alerts-box-through-javascript), but does it have to be so complicated? Really?

Comment: The solution is about 5 lines of Javascript. I don't think you can reasonably call that complicated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically create Bootstrap alerts box through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082330/dynamically-create-bootstrap-alerts-box-through-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Referenced the solution and now came up with this:

HTML:

```
<div id='alert' class='hide'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showAlert(message) {
      $('#alert').html("<div class='alert alert-error'>"+message+"</div>");
      $('#alert').show();
    }
showAlert('variable');
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juto/SDLpJ/).

Answer (score 8):

As simple as: `$("#alert").text("My new Text");`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "button" id = "clickme" value="Click me!"/>
<div id = "alert_placeholder"></div>
<script>
bootstrap_alert = function() {}
bootstrap_alert.warning = function(message) {
            $('#alert_placeholder').html('<div class="alert"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><span>'+message+'</span></div>')
        }

$('#clickme').on('click', function() {
            bootstrap_alert.warning('Your text goes here');
});
</script>​
```